# ASP.NET MVC Create function not working on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I've created a page that uses entity framework to retrieve/Display info in the database I've also got create functionality in a partial view on the same page but it doesn't save/insert data.

Here is my Home View:

```
@model IEnumerable<TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
<li class="one">
    <h5>Please begin creating your network structure:</h5> <button id="modal-opener">Add a new building</button>

</li>
<li class="two">

</li>
</ol>

<div class="Container">

<div class="Box1">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {<div>
            <h4 class="Heading">@item.buildingName</h4>
            <h4 class="Heading">@item.buildingNumber</h4>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc1</p>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc2</p>
            <p>@item.buildingDesc3</p>
        </div>
        }
</div>
</div>

<div id="Modal" title="Building Details">
@Html.Partial("buildForm", new TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo())
</div>
```

Here is my partial View:

```
@model TerminalHost.Models.buildingInfo

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
<legend>buildingInfo</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.buildingNumber)
</div>
....
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") 
</div>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And This is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    thDB _db = new thDB();

    public ActionResult building()
    {
        var buildingModel = _db.buildings.ToList();//you have to remove the FirstOrDefault() extension method

        return View(buildingModel);
    }

    public ActionResult buildForm()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult buildForm(buildingInfo buildinginfo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.buildings.Add(buildinginfo);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView(buildinginfo);
    }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(_db != null)
        {
            _db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I've attempted to replicate the same code as the scaffold template that is created to do the CRUD functions but they are separated out into different views whereas I want them all on one page.

Comment: Start by using the debugger. Does it enter the `buildForm(buildingInfo buildinginfo)` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need it's to tell your partial view the Action to call.
Could you change this line:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

To

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("builForm","Home"))
```

And in your Action:

```
HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult buildForm(buildingInfo buildinginfo)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _db.buildings.Add(buildinginfo);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return PartialView(buildinginfo);//instead of return this you can redirect to Index so you can see the update. Just a suggestion
}
```